# Proof of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{1/n}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{1/n}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2} dx$$

I just have no idea how to solve this, can anyone help me out, also is there any methods to solve this kind problems.

Firstly, I thought I should integrate this, so
$$a_n = \int_0^{1/n} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}dx $$
using partial fractian
$$\int_0^{1/n} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}dx = \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{2\sqrt{x}}- \int\sqrt{x}\ln(1+x^2)$$
then I partical fraction again, but I find I still can not get a useful result.

So, I thought maybe I can zooming the $a_n$

then I get

$$ \int_0^{1/n} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}dx > \int_0^{1/n} \frac{x}{1+x^2}$$

and

$$ \int_0^{1/n} \frac{x}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2)|_0^{1/n}=\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+(\frac{1}{n})^2)$$

So, we know

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{1/n}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2} dx>\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+(\frac{1}{n})^2)$$

using the limit comparison test

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+(\frac{1}{n})^2)}{(\frac{1}{n})^2} = 1 $$（L'Hospital's rule）

So, we find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+(\frac{1}{n})^2)$is convergent, but we can not use comparison test because greater than a convergent series we get nothing, and I just stuck here.

I have already added many things, but it is still closed, so I just write this, try to reopen it.

Comment: Actually there were 3 exact duplicates! (the 2 others are now linked to the one just mentionned). Found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cint_0%5E%7B1%2Fn%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Ea%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7D%20dx%24&p=1).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146051/discussion-on-question-by-stanley-proof-of-convergence-of-sum-n1-infty); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.